# Strip body events through js, other means

Tags: javascript

I'm using a third party service that is employing this code

```
<body onLoad="execWindowOnloadQueue(); " onUnload="" class=" checkout">
```

I want to strip all of this and have it just be `<body>`

Thanks for any help

Comment: How are you integrating this code?  Is it already present in the page or are you adding it using innerHTML/DOM methods?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's built-in to a template and I have no ability to edit it directly. I do have the ability to integrate js that acts on it though.

Comment: Do you know what `execWindowOnloadQueue()` does?

Comment: No, but I can read about it. Thanks. Are we allowed to ask "help me diagnose why my web page is misbehaving" type questions here? That would actually be more helpful, I wasn't sure though.

Comment: Did any of the answers help? If yes please check one so this topic can be considered closed, if not please provide some feedback or an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is just to monkey-patch (aka override) the function to be an empty stub. ie: since the body-onload happens after all other resources have been loaded, just define this function after all others, eg:

```
function execWindowOnloadQueue() {}
```

The alternative is to modify the DOM after the opening body tag, but before the closed tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").each(function() {
  var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
    return item.name;
  });

  // now use jQuery to remove the attributes
  var b = $(this);
  $.each(attributes, function(i, item) {
    b.removeAttr(item);
  });
});
```

Or if you want pure javascript

```
var b = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
for (var i = 0, attrs = b.attributes, l = attrs.length; i < l; i++){
    b[0].removeAttribute(attrs.item(i));
}
```